# Bloquear una casilla cuando otra está activada Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, checkbox

Tengo un formulario que se encarga de una gestión de productos.

En él, tengo dos campos que requieren una casilla de verificación (`Prestado` y `Definitivo`).

He intentado aplicar la lógica, pero no he conseguido mucho.

```
Private Sub Prestado_AfterUpdate()
If Prestado.Value = -1 Then
Definitivo.Value = False
End Sub
```

Con esto, no cambia nada. Si seleccionas el otro, ambos se siguen aplicando.

No sé si es posible hacer algo como que, cuando la casilla `Prestado` esté checkeada, bloquear la casilla `Definitivo`. Y si se desmarca `Prestado`, desbloquear `Definitivo`.

Buscando por Google tampoco he encontrado nada que me sirva. No es que sea importante, pero para evitar que ocurra el descuido de marcar ambos.

Comment: Para bloquear un control, mejor usa la propiedad `Enabled`. Algo tipo `If Prestado.Value=True then Definitivo.Enabled=False Else Definitivo.Enabled=True End If` debería funcionar

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes ¡Sí! Eso funcionó justo como quería :D ¿Redactas tú la respuesta o lo hago yo? Para dejar cerrada esta pregunta :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para bloquear un control, mejor usa la propiedad Enabled.

```
If Prestado.Value=True then
   Definitivo.Enabled=False
Else
   Definitivo.Enabled=True
End If
```

Otra opción sería la propiedad `Locked` . Puedes consultar ambas, a ver cual te viene mejor.

[Enabled (propiedad)](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/enabled-propiedad-9819dce1-4502-47c8-88ca-25038ac2cd47)

[Propiedad Locked](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/propiedad-locked-f3cf1b88-d3e3-40af-9620-aff60d83fd09)